# Designing a flexible API with support for Callbacks

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, api-design, callbacks

I am writing a Java library that needs to make http GET && POST requests. There will be two types of users of this library:

1. Those with understanding of **callbacks** and know how to use them.
2. Those that....don't.

So please consider the following two methods:

```
public void methodWithCallback(ServiceCallback callback) {
    try {
        // GET && POST code that cannot really be abstracted to a separate method
    } catch (IOException e) {
        callback.onError(e);
        callback = null;
    }
    callback.onSuccess(response);
    callback = null;
}

public Response methodWithoutCallback() throws IOException {

    try {
        // again, GET && POST code that cannot really be abstracted to a separate method
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.log(e);
        throw e;
    }
    return response;
}
```

Above code seems dirty to me, mainly because it has **duplication of code** to send the request. Also if I were writing a lot of such kind of methods, my code will very soon **double up** to hardly maintainable spaghetti.

I considered allowing the client to **set a callback** by providing a method like `setCallback(Callback callback)`, and then have one general `method` that  notifies the callback if it is NOT null. But this also seems dirty because I would be then writing a **lot** of `if null` checks!

What are your thoughts on it? What would be the desirable design pattern here that you would recommend?

Comment: Can your users cope with **Futures** or **Promises**?

Comment: I doubt so...I am providing this library to computer science students at uni. While some of them might can, I think most of them are still newbie java students. And I was just thinking of providing both levels of students with easily accessible methods. But since you are suggesting a different approach, I assume my approach isn't really a recommended practice?

Comment: Well, you may have to settle for converting the asynchrony into asynchronous methods, then.

Comment: You could implement the callback-free version in terms of the callback version, by having it pass in a callback that throws the exception/saves the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you can use one method (for each service function) and differentiate *callbackful* and *callbackless* version by either allowing `null` callback to be passed (idea#1) or by using callback to be registered by `setCallback` like your second idea (idea#2).

#### Callback as argument (idea#1)

```
public Response method(ServiceCallback callback) throws IOException {
    try {
        // GET && POST code that cannot really be abstracted to a separate method
        /* In your code you handle the response outside the try block,
           it can raise NullPointerException because you set callback 
           to null, and onSuccess is also called even it is an error. */
        return handleSuccess(response, callback);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        /* Return statement is needed because the method signature requires it. */
        return handleError(e, callback);
        /* If you use this two line version below, you can make handleError 
           return void. */
        // handleError(e, callback);
        // return null;
    }
}

private Response handleSuccess(Response response, ServiceCallback callback) {
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.onSuccess(response);
    }
    /* I personally prefer to also return the result even the callback exists;
       otherwise just move the line below into if block and return null here. */
    return response;
}

private Response handleError(IOException e, ServiceCallback callback) throws IOException {
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.onError(e);
    } else {
        logger.log(e); /* because I assume you want to log it */
        throw e;
    }
    /* I assume there is no response if error occurred. */
    return null;
}
```

#### Callback as a field (idea#2)

```
public Response method() throws IOException {
    try {
        // GET && POST code that cannot really be abstracted to a separate method
        return handleSuccess(response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return handleError(e);
    }
}

private Response handleSuccess(Response response) {
    if (this.callback != null) {
        this.callback.onSuccess(response);
    }
    return response;
}

private Response handleError(IOException e) throws IOException {
    if (this.callback != null) {
        this.callback.onError(e);
    } else {
        logger.log(e);
        throw e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, indeed helpful approach that I didn't think of :)

Comment: @JoelMin I updated my answer by adding reason why handling *success* inside `try` block, please read it. Thank you